# Joomla: where is $tableClass defined and what does JTable:getInstance returns?

Tags: php, joomla, k2

I have very little knowledge about joomla core and PHP. In order to better handle my website, I am trying to read a small part of joomla core, when I come across this function `JTable:getInstance`, (libararies\joomla\table\table.php line268), it returns

```
    return new $tableClass($db);
```

To understand what `getInstance` returns, I need to know how this `$tableClass` is defined, so I searched it in all php files in my website, although there are lots of references, even some so-called 'definitions' as [this page](http://phpcrossref.com/xref/joomla/_variables/tableClass.html) points out, none of them is what I am looking for. I am expecting something like

```
class tableClass{...}
```

Furthermore, from other php files, there are these lines:

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
$row->hit($id);
```

So it looks to me, what is returned by `getInstance` should be an object that has a member `hit()`, so I am expecting something like

```
class tableClass{...
    function hit(){
    .....
    }
}
```

But this kind of code is nowhere to be found, so I am stuck here and definitely need help.

Some of my thoughts: Is $tableClass really a class? I notice that it has a `$`, which all other classes don't have? If it is not a class, then why it could be invoked like this `new $tableClass`? I really need to understand these basics but it is kind of hard to google keyword `$`.

Comment: `$tableClass` is a variable name.  I assume that in K2 they are creating a lot of JTable instances and that it is efficient to have some methods that take an instantiated class name as a parameter.  That is that they could (as an example) have an array of class names and put creating instances of those classes inside a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

The full method is pasted below. When calling JTable::getInstance you must pass $type as an argument. The getInstance method then uses $type to define $tableClass as you can see below.

```
// Sanitize and prepare the table class name.
$type       = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $type);
$tableClass = $prefix . ucfirst($type);
```

The method then proceeds to load (import) the class if it's not already and then finally calls return new $tableClass($db);

So $tableClass is just a dynamic variable based on the $type argument.

In your example above:

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
```

The $type and $prefix arguments are translated into the following:

return new TableK2Item($db);

So if you search for TableK2Item you should indeed find that class which has a hit() method.

So $tableClass is actually defined in the getInstance method.

Does this make sense?

```
/**
 * Static method to get an instance of a JTable class if it can be found in
 * the table include paths.  To add include paths for searching for JTable
 * classes see JTable::addIncludePath().
 *
 * @param   string  $type    The type (name) of the JTable class to get an instance of.
 * @param   string  $prefix  An optional prefix for the table class name.
 * @param   array   $config  An optional array of configuration values for the JTable object.
 *
 * @return  mixed    A JTable object if found or boolean false if one could not be found.
 *
 * @link    https://docs.joomla.org/JTable/getInstance
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function getInstance($type, $prefix = 'JTable', $config = array())
{
    // Sanitize and prepare the table class name.
    $type       = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $type);
    $tableClass = $prefix . ucfirst($type);

    // Only try to load the class if it doesn't already exist.
    if (!class_exists($tableClass))
    {
        // Search for the class file in the JTable include paths.
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.path');

        $paths = self::addIncludePath();
        $pathIndex = 0;

        while (!class_exists($tableClass) && $pathIndex < count($paths))
        {
            if ($tryThis = JPath::find($paths[$pathIndex++], strtolower($type) . '.php'))
            {
                // Import the class file.
                include_once $tryThis;
            }
        }

        if (!class_exists($tableClass))
        {
            // If we were unable to find the class file in the JTable include paths, raise a warning and return false.
            JLog::add(JText::sprintf('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_NOT_FOUND', $type), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }
    }

    // If a database object was passed in the configuration array use it, otherwise get the global one from JFactory.
    $db = isset($config['dbo']) ? $config['dbo'] : JFactory::getDbo();

    // Instantiate a new table class and return it.
    return new $tableClass($db);
}
```